# linking many to many tables using one single association table

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

Im creating a database which primarily associates data to data, I would not like to constrain which table records can be associated to other (will be handled on the UI side)

Instead of creating association tables for each many to many relationship, I was thinking of creating one "linking" table which relates records using a composite primary key consisting of [tablename]+[record_id]  linking to [tablename] + [record_id]  The image below provides an illustration: 
[image]

What is this design construct called (if any) and are there better/more standard ways to implement such functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure what that's called; it looks like a modification of an EAV design.  If you're using a relational database, it would be best to follow traditional rules of normalization (for performance and validity).

Comment: I looked at EAV, which is similar to the basic attributes table, I guess, the more correct solution to implement here would be an attributes table, which simply defines a set of attribute types for each table.  The only difference here, is that you can have complex tables for each of the association child tables.

Comment: The more correct implementation would be to normalize your database IF you are planning on using an RDBMS; traditional database systems are optimized for traditional database normalization.